# Cast base type to inherited type with out Intilization

Tags: c#, oop

Is there anyway to cast\convert an object to an inherited type directly?

```
class Base
{
    void Process()
    {
    Base obj = new Derived1();
    }
}

class Derived1 : Base
{
}

class Derived2 : Base
{
}
```

How can i covert the object `obj` to type of `Derived2` without intializing or creating a new instance of `Derived2`?

Comment: You cannot change a `Derived1` object into a `Derived2` object even though they both inherit from `Base`.

Comment: Try an interface instead.

Answer (score 1):

From your example you cannot change an object from `Derived1` to `Derived2`. Your code is creating a new instance of `Derived1` into an object type of `Base` this is fine as `Derived1` will have the same signature as `Base`. However `Base` does not have the same signature as `Derived1` and you are not able to convert to an inherited type. Although `Derived1` has a base class of `Base` does not ensure the signatures are the same.

This is also true in user defined conversions using `implicit` or `explicit` operators. You cannot write your own conversions from a base class as this would provide multiple valid conversions.

The only way you can convert `Base` to `Derived2` (or another derived class) is to create a new reference of `Derived2` and copy your properties to this new class. However in a real world situation this is not only time consuming, but typically a flaw in your design process.

In most cases you invoke a method which returns an object of a specific type. For example `Base` (which really has not methods or properties) should define how the object acts and the common properties and methods for that object. Where `Derived1` and `Derived2` can build on this common signature. Your design here is quite flexible but in a common scenario you could essentially re-write your objects similar to the example below. Where you will notice there is not conversions required.

First define an interface for the base class. Although this is not required adds a concrete level of uniformity between your classes (again not required).

```
interface IBase
{
    string Name { get; set; }

    void DoWork();
}
```

This simply defines an interface with one `property` and one `method`. Next write your simply base class as:

```
class Base : IBase
{
    string name = "Base Class: ";

    public virtual string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    public virtual void DoWork()
    {
        //Base class does no work...
    }
}
```

The base class `Base` inherits from `IBase` and implements both the method and the property from the interface. In this example I also marked the property and method as `virtual` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9fkccyh4.aspx so any class that inherits from `Base` may override the member. So in this class the name is set (using a backing field) and has implemented the `DoWork` method which actually does nothing.

Next I define another class `Derived1` which inherits from `Base`.

```
class Derived1 : Base
{
    public override void DoWork()
    {
        this.Name = "Derived 1 did some work.....";
    } 
}
```

Now `Derived1` inherits from `Base` and `Base` inherits the interface `IBase`. `Base` has defined the interface `IBase` and with the `virtual` keyword on both the method and the property. This means that `Derived1` may `override` a member of `Base` (but doesnt have too)... The `Derived1` class will now override the method `DoWork` and set the string `Derived 1 did some work....` to the property `Name`.

We can then define a second class that inherits from `Base` as `Derived2`

```
class Derived2 : Base
{
    string name;

    public override string Name
    {
        get { return this.name; }
        set { this.name = value; }
    }

    public override void DoWork()
    {
        this.Name = base.Name + " - Derived 2 did some work.....";
    } 
}
```

Just like before the new class `Derived2` inherits from `Base` and in this instance is overriding both the property `Name` and the method `DoWork` however in this instance the do work method is access the property `Name` from the `base` class by using the `base` keyword. This essentially sets the name of `Derived2` to the name of the base class `Base` and appends ' - Derived 2 did some work.....'.

Now this doesnt actually answer your question as you cant convert `Derived2` to `Derived` or `Derived2` to `Base` however provides the signature to build your classes against.

Now to use this in a real world we (as said before) execute methods or receive events that return our object type.

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var baseObj = getBase();
        baseObj.DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine("Base Name:" + baseObj.Name);

        var d1 = getDerived1();
        d1.DoWork();
        Console.WriteLine("Derived 1 Name:" + d1.Name);

        var d2 = getDerived2();
        d2.DoWork();

        Console.WriteLine("Derived 2 Name:" + d2.Name);
        Console.ReadKey();
    }

    static IBase getBase()
    {
        return new Base();
    }

    static IBase getDerived1()
    {
        return new Derived1();
    }

    static IBase getDerived2()
    {
        return new Derived2();
    }

}
```

As seen below we have 3 methods that return an instance of `IBase` these instances will all have matching signatures as they all inherit from the same interface. However in each method we are constructing new objects of different types. When the method `DoWork` is executed for each object the underlying methods are called on each object type.

Now this may be a long winded way of saying it can't be done but hopefully this shows you how you could achieve what are looking for by modifying how you define your objects.

Cheer

Answer (score 0):

You cant do it, simply because `Derived1` is not `Derived2` *(Derived1 != Derived2)*.

A good analogy would be, your base can be classified as a **Fruit**, and `Derived1` and `Derived2` can be **Apple** and **Banana**. In a bigger context, yes they're in the same categorization as a fruit. But you cant convert a banana to an apple and vise versa.

What you can do though is create your own converter, here is a quick mockup i created to get you started.

```
public static class ObjectConverter<T>
{
    public static TTo Convert<TFrom, TTo>(TFrom value)
        where TFrom : T
        where TTo : T, new()
    {
        TTo result = new TTo(); // creates an instance of the target type
        var baseProperties = value.GetType().GetProperties() // gets all properties
            .Where(x => x.DeclaringType == typeof(T)); // based on target type
        foreach (var prop in baseProperties)
        {
            prop.SetValue(result, prop.GetValue(value)); // sets value to the target
        }
        return result;
    }
}
```

And consume like this.

```
Base item = new Derived1(); // base object
item.Age = 18; // properties existing on the base
item.Name = "Sasha";
Derived2 convertedItem = ObjectConverter<Base>.Convert<Derived1, Derived2>(item as Derived1);
```

Comment: Great idea, however this assumes that TTo has a parameter less constructor and creates a new instace of TTo copying the properties from TTFrom. Although this could work once you have converted to `Derived2` you have created an new instance of `Derived2` and any changes to `Base` are not reflected in `Derived2`. Understanably this is a good attempt to overcome a direct cast from a base type. Cheers.

Comment: @Nico Yup, I'm just assuming this code based on his example, so he's free to modify this code based on his preference. Either pass an instance of the `TTo` on the param of `Convert` or reflect the constructor of `TTo`

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for something like this. And the state design pattern fulfills it
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/489136/UnderstandingplusandplusImplementingplusStateplusP